# MySQL Database connection disconnected after few minute

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsf

I am working on Spring+Hibernate+JSF but if i am ideal on a page for few minute i am getting exception when trying some Database query

```
 The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,615,049 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 27 milliseconds ago.

Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:474)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Is this issue due to any configuration in my project or its database vendor issue
in web.xml i made this entry

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>
          30
   </session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

Connection pool

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/ccc" />
                <property name="user" value=" hariom" />
                <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: this question has been answered many times, search it

Comment: `session-timeout` setting is about http sessions and isn't related to database. To answer your question we should know more about your setup, especially about connection pool which you use. Is it Apache DBCP, c3p0, BoneCP or something else? How you configure datasource?

Comment: Added connection pool settings

Comment: Looks to me like the database server is closing the connection after X minutes of inactivity and the pool is not setup to deal with stale connections.

Comment: So what i have to do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should add  this property ;

```
<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
```

This will validate the connection ,and if mysql closed the connection your app won't try to send packet.

Comment: But it should throw exception because if it closed it will not reconnect

Comment: your app understands the connections state with that validate query which is for mysql, and if required it will reconnect.

Comment: No other thing i have to change like pool size etc.

Comment: After adding above properties in my applicationcontext.xml file my application not working and not able to create the session

Comment: what is the exception ?

Comment: Can not create session

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext